# struts exception while running the application

Tags: java, struts2

When run the application it shows some thing like this.

Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
    The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

add.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Create/Edit</h3>
        <s:form action="#{studentController.add()}">
            <s:textfield id="id"  placeholder="Student Id" value="#{studentController.s.studentId}" required="true" requiredLabel="This field is manditory"></s:textfield><br>
            <s:textfield id="fname"  placeholder="First Name" value="#{studentController.s.firstName}" required="true" requiredLabel="This field is manditory"></s:textfield><br>
            <s:textfield id="lname"  placeholder="Last Name" value="#{studentController.s.lastName}" required="true" requiredLabel="This field is manditory"></s:textfield><br>
            <s:submit name="save" value="Save"></s:submit>

        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's seems you are accessing JSP directly w/o going to action. It should be Action -> JSP.

Comment: Can you provide any example

Comment: because i am new upon this

Comment: Which url do you access? Go to action url.

Comment: Where is your struts.xml?